# Stack pointer of the interrupt stack

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt

Linux kernel has separate stacks for user mode and kernel mode process and also some special stacks. One of this special stacks is interrupt stack with the size 16 kilobytes placed in the `irq_stack_union`:

```
union irq_stack_union {
    char irq_stack[IRQ_STACK_SIZE];
    struct {
        char gs_base[40];
        unsigned long stack_canary;
    };
};
```

There is definition of the pointer to this stack - `irq_stack_ptr`. As I understand correctly this `irq_stack_ptr` must point to the end of the `irq_stack` or in another words to `irq_stack + IRQ_STACK_SIZE - 1`, but definition of the `irq_stack_ptr` is:

```
DEFINE_PER_CPU(char *, irq_stack_ptr) =
    init_per_cpu_var(irq_stack_union.irq_stack) + IRQ_STACK_SIZE - 64;
```

Why we subtract `64` bytes from the end of the `irq_stack_union.irq_stack` here?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with linux internals to answer this, but in other OSes a common trick is to put per-thread data such as the current task/process pointer there, as kernel stacks are usually aligned and fixed size so it's easy to find the top.  Maybe linux uses this area to store the current CPU number or to allow code to detect that it's in an interrupt context.  Just speculating, though.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think about this too: "current task/process pointer there", there no need to store cpu number here because we can find it easily with the API that provided by the Linux kernel, but pointer to the previous task_struct very similar. But can't find something in the code

Comment: But how is that API implemented? Using the APIC to get CPU number is probably expensive, so caching it at the top of the stack seems like a plausible optimization.

Comment: There is smp_processor_id macro for this purpose and seems that 64 bytes is too many for the pointer on the previous process or something like this

Answer (score 0):

It seems like nobody knows anymore.

> There has been a 64-byte gap at the end of the irq stack for at least
>   12 years.  It predates git history, and I can't find any good reason
>   for it.  Remove it.  What's the worst that could happen?

http://git.kernel.org/linus/4950d6d48a0c43cc61d0bbb76fb10e0214b79c66